# social sign-up and writing to database

Tags: amazon-cognito

I need help with a web app (in Nextjs) for the following scenario. I have a form where a user can sign-up for our service, choosing to fill out a form or by social login (google).
We have Cognito as the identity provider and when a user fills out the form I write his data in Cognito (which also authenticates the email) and then in the database (for our purposes).
When the user uses the google button however, I can successfully have the user inserted into Cognito pool but I cannot find a  way to concurrently write at least his email into our database. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: used a Post authentication lambda trigger according to the documentation [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-authentication.html#aws-lambda-triggers-post-authentication-example).
To import Axios I followed this tutorial:
[tutorial for using external dependencies in an AWS Lambda function](https://egghead.io/lessons/aws-use-external-dependencies-in-an-aws-lambda-function)